# npm compiling warning (Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";" )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been getting errors on the code below. How do I fix it, please???. The issue is on line 22. It's not compiling on npm//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import './App.css';

const particlesOptions = {
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 30,
      density: {
        enable: true,
        value_area: 800
      }
    }
  }  
}

function App() {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: '',
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Particles className='particles'
        params={particlesOptions}
      />
      <Navigation />
      <Logo />
      <Rank />
      <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange}/>
       {/*<FaceRecognition />*/}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is a `constructor` doing inside a function ? Just remove it, or convert the function to a `Class` (*and add a `render` method*).

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli is right. You might be confusing `Functional Components` and `Class Components`. Functional components are more popular now, but you should make sure you know the difference. The constructor() function used to be very popular in class components, but it's not used in functional components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gabriele mentioned in the comments. You have kind of a mix of a function component and a class component. To make this a proper class component we need to extend `React.Component` and we need a render method.

```
import React from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import './App.css';

const particlesOptions = {
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 30,
      density: {
        enable: true,
        value_area: 800
      }
    }
  }  
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: '',
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Particles className='particles'
          params={particlesOptions}
        />
        <Navigation />
        <Logo />
        <Rank />
        <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange}/>
         {/*<FaceRecognition />*/}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```